# delegate remains nil

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, segue

I'm trying to send data from one ViewController to another with delegate, but can't seem to get the right instance

I've tried setting the delegate at different places within the receiving ViewController including ViewDidLoad, but the delegate in the sending ViewController is always nil.

From what I've learned, it's an average problem everybody seems to go through, and I've read quite a number of samples, tried them, but to no avail. I don't know if I'm leaving something out or not. Please shed some light if you will.

Below is what I ended up with.

The sending ViewController:

```
protocol CreateChatDelegate: class{
    func appendChatData(_ sender: CreateChatViewController)
}

class CreateChatViewController: UIViewController {
     weak var delegate: CreateChatDelegate!

    @IBAction func createChat(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    delegate?.appendChatData(self)

        if delegate == nil {
            print("delegate unsuccessful")
        } else {
            print("delegate successful")
        }
}
```

The receiving ViewController:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    var createChatViewController: CreateChatViewController!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    ...

    }
}

extension ViewController: CreateChatDelegate {  
    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // get the reference to the ViewController
        self.createChatViewController = segue.destination as? CreateChatViewController

        // set it as delegate
        self.createChatViewController?.delegate = self
        print("ViewController: delegate successful")
        }
    }

    func appendChatData(_ sender: CreateChatViewController) {
        print("ViewController: CreateChatDelegate called")
    }

}
```

this code outputs "delegate unsuccessful", because delegate is always nil

Comment: `print(type(of: segue.destination))` inside `prepareForSegue...` and see what is the destination type.

Comment: Thanks. What should I do if `prepareForSegue` is not being called in the first place? I've noticed that this seems to be the problem.

Comment: What iOS and Xcode version you use?

Comment: Check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are using is incorrect. You should use the new one:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    ....
}
```

Notice the `override` keyword? if you don't see this when you are writing the viewController methods, It means that you are NOT calling the original method and misspelled the function signature.

**NOTE:** if you are targeting older iOS and using older Xcode, the method name may be different, you should write the name of the method and let the *AutoComplete* help you with the correct one.

Comment: Yes! I was curious about that, there being two different methods for exactly the same thing. I've changed it to `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {` and the segue finally seems to be called. Now all I need to do is get to call `func appendChatData`

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!!! I just have one concern. It's no error, but I get this warning: **Warning: Attempt to present <ViewController: 0x7fb5e70d5f50> on <CreateChatViewController: 0x7fb5e4ccbc60> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**   Do you happen to know what it is?

Answer (score 0):

To successsfuly configure segue you need to make sure that

1- Navigation is triggered by

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"segue",sender:nil)
```

2- Force-unwrap

```
self.createChatViewController = segue.destination as! CreateChatViewController
```

as `as?` cast may fail silently for some reason

Comment: I really appreciate the help. So, I've tried putting `performSegue(withIdentifier:"segue",sender:nil)` under `viewDidLoad() {}`, but I always get a termination error _'Receiver (<.ViewController: ...) has no segue with identifier 'segue''_.

Comment: I've named the segue "segue" through Main.storyboard. Did I approach it the wrong way?

Comment: put it for test inside `viewDidAppear` and replace segue with your own name in storyboard

Comment: Thanks, I tried it in `viewDidAppear` too, with same results. Am I not mistaken to think the `withIdenifier: ` here refers to the 'identifier' box in 'Storyboard segue' ? Because I keep on getting _'Receiver (<.ViewController: ...) has no segue with identifier 'segue'' '_

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that prepareForSegue() method is called. Then make sure that it is called for the CreateChatViewController i.e.

```
if let destination = segue.destination as? CreateChatViewController {
    //Do all the stuff there e.g.
    destination.delegate = self
}
```

If your prepareForSegue() method is not called then set the action properly so it will fire the prepareForSegue() method then you will get the delegate value in the CreateChatViewController.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It seems that ` prepareForSegue() ` method is not called.